# WHERE NOT EXISTS sql with insert into

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO friend(`uId`,`friendId`) VALUES (?,?)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT uId,friendId FROM friend WHERE uId=? && friendId=?
```

Is my sql correct? I want to check whether a record exist using WHERE NOT EXISTS, then only insert into it if it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you need to check first? Clue: You don't!

Comment: @Strawberry because I don't want to mess up my complicated table :P

Comment: The solution is to add a UNIQUE index on (uid,friendid), and then you can just use either INSERT IGNORE or INSERT...UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: @Strawberry friendId must have duplicate records so I can't do that

Comment: friendid can, but (id,friendid) cannot. So you CAN and MUST do that!

Comment: my record must able to do like this

id=1
friendId=2

friendId=2
id=2

Comment: if friendId is unique, it means friendId cannot have duplicate record..

Comment: Create a UNIQUE index on (uid,friendid).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52313/discussion-between-user3522457-and-strawberry)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the data look like but you would do this kind of insert something like this..

```
INSERT INTO friend_One (`uId`,`friendId`) 
SELECT f.uId,f.friendId 
FROM friend f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM  friend_One
                  WHERE uId= f.Uid 
                  AND friendId= f.friendId)
```

Typically the table you are checking against for existance of a record is different than the table you are selecting from. here this query as it is doesnt make much sense. But I guess this was just a demo query.

Comment: where is the values ?

Comment: You dont use values clause where using Select statement to insert data, The returned result set of the Select statement will provide Values for insert statement.

Comment: @DownVoter care to leave a comment ?

Comment: Except for the penultimate sentence, this answer is the antithesis of 'right'

Comment: @Strawberry Would you like to elaborate a little bit more what is so antithesis of 'right' ?

Comment: @M.Ali what if the record doesn't exist? the query do nothing? That's not what I want

Comment: Are you are you are Inserting into, selecting from and checking against the same table ???

Comment: But you are selecting from the same table. In simple english you are Selecting records from table A which do not exist in table A and inserting into Table A, Does this make any sense ???